# Can you combine objects created in two separate classes to create a third object in a third class?

Tags: java

I have a Name object created in a Name class and an Address object created in a Address class. Can I combine these two objects to create a MailingLabel Object in a MailingLabel class?

First class

```
public class Name 
{
    private String firstName;
    private char middleInitial;
    private String lastName;

    public Name (String fn, char mi, String ln)
    {
        firstName = fn;
        middleInitial = mi;
        lastName = ln;
    }
```

Second class

```
public class Address 
{
    private int streetNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String streetType;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int zip;

    public Address (int snum, String sn, String st, String c, String s, int z)
    {
        streetNumber = snum;
        streetName = sn;
        streetType = st;
        city = c;
        state = s;
        zip = z;

    }
```

The goal is for MailingLabel to print out a toString that looks like

```
            Millicent X Feniwick

            1600 Huckleberry Lane

            Chelsea, NJ 15483
```

Comment: I believe you are asking about [Composition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/).

Comment: You have to be more specific in terms of what is the problem you are trying to resolve, please add some code as well as labels to understand the technologies and scope of the question.

Comment: Yes. Create new class named `MailingLabel` and add two (preferably private) fields. One of type `Name` and one of type `Address`. Add getters/setters. It would be also nice to have a constructor taking both objects as parameters.

Comment: When you say "created in", I assume you mean "created from".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MailingLabel{
    private Address addressname;
    private Name theName;

    public MailingLabel(Address addressname, Name theName){
        this.addressname = addressname;
        this.theName = theName;
    }
}
```

Based on what you asked, I guess this is what you need.